# Proof by induction that $2^n+1 \leq 3^n$ for all positive integers $n$

Tags: inequality, induction

I am having trouble proving the following inequality:

*For all positive integers $n$, $2^n+1 \leq 3^n$*

The examples we have worked with in class so far have all involved the same integer on both sides of the equation, such as:

*For all positive integers $n$, $2^n \leq 2^{n+1}-2^{n-1}-1$*

The $3$ in the equation I am trying to prove is throwing me off. Also, I am not sure how to deal with the $+1$ on the left hand side of the inequality.

Comment: how far have you got with the proof? where are you stuck - base case, inductive step, etc?

Comment: **Hint:** Since $n$ is a positive integer, the statement $2^n+1\leq 3^n$ is identical to the statement $2^n<3^n$ which should be clear.

Comment: Ah, my apologies. I was able to do the base case of $n=1$. I have tried working with the left hand side of the inequality as is, by assuming $k$ is an element of the positive integers and substituting $k+1$ in for $k$. I am stuck once I rewrite $2^{k+1}$ as $2*2^k$ though.

Comment: If you know that $\displaystyle \forall n\in \mathbb N\left(3^n=\sum \limits_{k=0}^n\left({n\choose k} 2^k\right)\right)$, it is rather trivial.

Comment: In general, if working from one side does not work, try from the other side. Sometimes you may even need to work from both sides to try to reach something in the middle. For instance, to prove $n^3 \le 3^n$ for natural $n$, if you work from the left you might get $(n+1)^3 \le 3^n + 3n^2+3n+1$ and still have a long way to go. But if you work from the right you get $3^{n+1} \ge 3n^3 \ge (n+1)^3$ for $n \ge 3$ since $(1+1/n)^3 \le (4/3)^3 < 3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You assume that $2^k+1\le 3^k$. Then you want to prove that under this assumption, we will have that $2^{k+1}+1\le3^{k+1}$.

$$\begin{align}2^{k+1}+1&=(2\times2^k)+1\\
&=2(2^k+1)-1\\
&=(2^k+1)+(2^k+1)-1\\
&\le 3^k+3^k-1\\
&=3^{k+1}-1-3^k\\
&\le 3^{k+1}\end{align}$$

Comment: I believe this is where I am having trouble. I am struggling to see how you are able to move from $(2 \times 2^k)+1$ to $2(2^k+1)-1$.

Comment: @automattik Ok, see the new edit. The key is to engineer the $3^{k+1}$ term, which is done by adding and subtracting $3^k$.

Comment: I am understanding a little better I think. We want to have $2^k+1$ so that we can substitute it with $3^k$, which makes sense to me. I am having trouble seeing where the $-1$ came from on the second line of the right hand side though. I feel like I am close to seeing it, but it is not clicking for me yet.

Comment: I just got it! It took a little bit of looking and thinking about it but I now see how to move from that first step to the second. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: @automattik no problem! glad to help

Answer (score 2):

When $n=1$ it is obviously true.

Suppose $2^k + 1 \le 3^k$ for $n=k$

You want to show that $2^{k+1} + 1 \le 3^{k+1}$

And to see this:
$$2^{k+1} + 1 = (2^k+ 1) + (2^k + 1) - 1$$
$$\le (3^k) + (3^k) -1$$
$$\le (3^k) + (3^k) + (3^k)=3^{k+1}$$

Comment: You have one too many $3^k$'s on the right hand side if you were taking this a single step at a time, having only applied the induction hypothesis, and an unnecessary $+1$ on the far right hand side.  Of course the third $+3^k$ is going to be a useful final step, but might be clearer to add by itself as its own step.

Comment: @JMoravitz I've modified to be more clear. But originally both additional 3k and +1 make sense, and I just skipped some steps as I thought it was obvious. Previously what I meant is that since my last equation is true, then it will lead to the conclusion - can you see that $+1$ is necessary (on my early version)?

Answer (score 1):

You have the following problem : To prove that for all $n \geq 1$ we have $2^n + 1 \leq 3^n$. (Note that the statement is not true for $n=0$).

This is equivalent to the statement that $2^n < 3^n$ for all $n \geq 1$. The rewrite is key, since it resolves the question of what to do with the $1$ that is sticking out. Upon request (although I request you to have a go first) I can provide a reason why the two statements are equivalent.

But from here we can proceed as usual. The base case is $n = 1$, which  gives $2 < 3$ which is true.

For the induction case, we *know* that $2^k < 3^k$, and we want to prove that $2^{k+1} < 3^{k+1}$.

When you have an inequality, then multiplying both sides by a positive number retains inequality.

So, if you know that $2^k < 3^k$, then multiplying both sides by $2$ gives you $2 \times 2^k < 2 \times 3^{k}$, or $2^{k+1} < 2 \times 3^k$.

Next, since $2 < 3$, multiply both sides by $3^k$, to get $2 \times 3^k < 3 \times 3^k$, or $2 \times 3^k < 3^{k+1}$.

Combine the statements above : $2^{k+1} < 2 \times 3^{k} < 3^{k+1}$. Hence, the statement is true for $k+1$, and hence in general.

What you need to take away from this proof is that equivalent rewriting can often simplify statements. If anything, all the others are fairly standard manipulations.

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time to show this. I am just not sure if my professor would allow rewrites like this, as she never did them for any of the in-class examples, so I don't think I can use your answer directly, but it will help me to keep an eye out for things like this in the future.

Comment: Would you like me to add a proof for the statement as is, rather than a rewrite? It is not effort for me (actually I am very happy, just coming out of good sleep after a good exam, so the , you know, "good samaritan" feeling is being expressed right now).

Comment: Sure if you would like. I am always happy to see different ways of solving problems, especially since some make more sense to me than others, even if they are all correct in the end.

Comment: Actually, I have seen proofs below and I believe that they are adequate. I would suggest that you accept one of them rather than mine, since you will not be able to use my rewrite immediately. Having said that, I request you to ask your professor about this, since I believe that it is a fairly important idea in induction.

Comment: Yes, I was able to understand with the help of you and another user. I will ask my professor about the rewriting though. Thank you again for your willingness to help me.

Comment: You are welcome!